# The smallest number

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

Some time ago I created a program to generate a table, and printed the first seven rows and columns.
Somehow however I forgot to print the headers and the title of the table.
I only remember that it was about smallest numbers, and thus numbers like 2190090 appearing seemed surprising.

If I just remembered what 'smallest number' 2190090 is, I might be able to make a nice puzzle out of it for stack exchange. However, I also have bad memory, so could you please help me?

What 'smallest number' is 2190090 according to the table below?

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| 16 | 2 | X | X | X | X | X |
| 2 | 24 | 18 | 6 | X | X | X |
| 4 | 6 | 12 | 360 | 30 | 150 | X |
| 2 | 18 | 6 | 30 | 60 | 123480 | 1210230 |
| 4 | 24 | 30 | 150 | 90 | 244230 | 2190090 |
| 2 | 6 | 12 | 150 | 22260 | 2940 | 86100 |

Comment: [This](http://oeis.org/A211889), [this](http://oeis.org/A061558) and [this](http://oeis.org/A113461) all look a bit relevant. They seem to point to arithmetic progressions of prime numbers. All numbers in the table are quite [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) - which might be a consequence of being common differences of arithmetic progressions of prime numbers.